Horror movie about teens who gathered in school basement for exorcism.
I am looking for a particular horror movie which I saw around 1998-2001. However, I can't find the name; long hours in Google didn't pay of. What I remember:

The plot was about group of teens who gathered in (I think) school basement for exorcism. 
One by one they are getting killed afterwards.
I particularly remember one episode in the toilet when one of the teens is looking through a key hole and the monster eye appears.
I think the title of the movie was the name of the demon who is killing people.


In your question you mention an episode. But you also speak of a movie. do you mean Scene instead of Episode? Or are you searching for a TV show?

@mattiav27 Lets say 1998-2001 that time range.

@Mango 1. There was a group of teens, they were calling the demon. Not one - a group 2. Well yeah. that's the point of horror movie usually :D 3. Not the toilet, but that ,,eye through a keyhole'' should be the main point 4. My early days is about 1998-2001, though I can be wrong. Also - how this is off topic, the main point is to discuss about the movies here

@mattiav27 Regarding early days, I edited the question to include date range Eimisas mentioned in a comment.

Not quite the correct time range, but the first film I thought of was Long Time Dead (2002)
A group of teens getting killed one by one (of course). They summon a demon during a seance. I don't remember a toilet scene but the Wikipedia plot description mentions one. 



